# MySQL TIMESTAMP value greater than '2038-01-19 03:14:07'

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm wondering what will happen after 2038-01-19 03:14:07 with table fields using `TIMESTAMP` as data type?

I always preferred `DATETIME` but you apparently can't assign `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value to that type. I mean, 28 years is not so long when you think about it (in my opinion anyway)... So what will happen to all those `TIMESTAMP` fields then?

Comment: I guess till then we will have MySQL 2038 that supports longer ranges. And hopefully no one will still be using MySQL 5

Comment: For the records, it's 2024 and MySQL still doesn't support ranges longer than 2038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be able to assign `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to a `DATETIME` column, but you can assign `NOW()` to it.

As for the y2k+38 issue, I'm willing to bet there will be newer versions of MySQL that will address this long before it is a real concern.

Comment: unfortunatly, to set NOW() I need to create a TRIGGER. While this is an acceptable solution, triggers don't show in PhpMyAdmin exports (but does with mysqldump) :/

Comment: You don't need to set a trigger to add `NOW()`.. it can be added in your insert/update query... Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I understand the default values and how to set NOW(). I was more curious about general opinion about TIMESTAMP vs DATETIME (my personal fav is DATETIME). But I'll just close this question and say, in conclusion, that I agree with the y2k+38 being resolved by that time with a newer version (hopefully!)